# SerialPort.Read(byte[], int32, int32) is not blocking but i want it to - how do I achieve?

Tags: c#, serial-port, blocking

I'm writing an interface for talking to a piece of test equipment. The equipment talks over a serial port and responds with a known number of bytes to each command I send it.

My current structure is:

- Send command
- Read number of specified bytes back
- Proceed with application

However, when I used SerialPort.Read(byte[], int32, int32), the function is not blocking. So, for example, if I call `MySerialPort.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bytesExpected);`, the function returns with less than the specified number of `bytesExpected`. Here is my code:

```
public bool ReadData(byte[] responseBytes, int bytesExpected, int timeOut)
{
    MySerialPort.ReadTimeout = timeOut;
    int bytesRead = MySerialPort.Read(responseBytes, 0, bytesExpected);
    return bytesRead == bytesExpected;
}
```

And I call this method like this:

```
byte[] responseBytes = new byte[13];
if (Connection.ReadData(responseBytes, 13, 5000))
    ProduceError();
```

My problem is that I can't ever seem to get it to read the full 13 bytes like I am telling it. If I put a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` right before my `SerialPort.Read(...)` everything works fine.

How can I force the `Read` method to block until either the timeOut is exceeded or the specified number of bytes are read?

Comment: Use the DataReceived event handler to read whatever bytes are available when the event fires. Add these bytes to a collection. In your ReadData method check if the collection has the number of bytes you need, and extract them from the collection. If not check later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is expected; most IO APIs allow you to specify the **upper** bound *only* - they are simply required to return at-least-one byte, unless it is an EOF in which case they can return a non-positive value. To compensate, you loop:

```
public bool ReadData(byte[] responseBytes, int bytesExpected, int timeOut)
{
    MySerialPort.ReadTimeout = timeOut;
    int offset = 0, bytesRead;
    while(bytesExpected > 0 &&
      (bytesRead = MySerialPort.Read(responseBytes, offset, bytesExpected)) > 0)
    {
        offset += bytesRead;
        bytesExpected -= bytesRead;
    }
    return bytesExpected == 0;
}
```

The only problem is you might need to reduce the timeout per iteration, by using a `Stopwatch` or similar to see how much time has passed.

Note that I also removed the `ref` on `responseBytes` - you don't need that (you don't re-assign that value).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the timeout to [`InfiniteTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.infinitetimeout.aspx).

Comment: No such luck. Read still returns with less than the specified number of bytes.

Comment: @michael.mankus indeed; no matter how large `bytesExpected` is, all that each call to `Read` is *required* to return is 1 byte, or non-positive for EOF. It is usually implemented such that if it has any data in the buffer, (some of) that data is returned *immediately*, rather than block.

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort.Read is expected to throw a TimeoutException in case no bytes are available before SerialPort.ReadTimeout.
So this method reads exactly the desired number or bytes, or throws an exception:

```
    public byte[] ReadBytes(int byteCount) {
        try
        {
            int totBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] rxBytes = new byte[byteCount];
            while (totBytesRead < byteCount) {
                int bytesRead = comPort.Read(rxBytes, totBytesRead, byteCount - totBytesRead);
                totBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }



            return rxBytes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){

            throw new MySerialComPortException("SerialComPort.ReadBytes error", ex);            
        }
    }
```